# Invest on real state vs other option

Tags: investing

I own half of a house that I rent out. I paid 20K and the current value of the house is 70K - 75K (so roughly 35K is mine).
The current state of the house is poor and a rent on the current condition is impossible.

I have 2 options

1. Get a loan of 65K to bought the other half and fix the house for a rent of 4.5K after taxes a year.
   Total invest of 85K. I will need 20 years to get the money back.
   After 20 years I will get a 100K house and the money back
2. Sold the house I will get 35K on my 20K. And I could invest the 35K in a 10% a year rate.
   After 20 Years without taking any cash out I will get 180K Cash

This is not my home, this is an investment.

Comment: I can't follow the math. Where is the "35k" coming from? And if you sell your house, where will you live?

Comment: "I will need 20 years to get the money back." This is not how to think about it. If you buy a house for 85K you _still have a house worth 85k_. It's more appropriate to say "it would take 20 years to double your investment", and even then you aren't taking growth in the real estate and rent into consideration (or expenses, which may even things out).

Comment: Do you live in this house, or are you living somewhere else?

Comment: Sounds like a homework question - what's the context of the question?

Comment: I will get the 35K if I sell the property at the current price

Comment: About the context of the question, I’m trying to decide to repair the house and rent or sold it and invest the money elsewhere. I don't live in the house and I have a job. This is a investment for the future using some extra money that I have

Comment: "And I could invest the 35K in a 10% a year rate"  WHERE ?!?!?!

Comment: ( @DStanley , regarding this enigmatic situation, i believe the "35" is simply one-half of the supposed sale price, "70 - 75". )

Comment: Yes!, sorry if I'm not clear enough. 35 will be a selling price of my half

Comment: @Fattie OK that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: @Guillermo I have edited your question to clarify the confusion from the comments. If anything is not accurate please correct it.

Answer (score 1):

So this is a pretty straightforward IRR problem with some unknown variables.

You have an asset that you can sell for 35K (forget what you paid for it - that's a *sunk cost*. You claim that you could invest it for 10% elsewhere - presumably with a similar level of risk as the rent house.

So that 10% would be your *required rate of return*. You would compare that to the rate of return on the house based on the cash flows.

I can already tell you that you won't get a 10% rate of return on the house, since the rent alone is only giving you a 5.3% return (4.5 / 85) and you haven't even considered the interest expense on the loan or other expenses like maintenance/taxes/insurance. If you're paying 3-4% on interest you might be lucky to break even. Yes, you'll have an asset that's appreciating in value, but unless that appreciation is 20% or so annually it wont get you to 10%.

But, for the sake of argument, you would take all of the cash flows in each year (initial 65K outlay, rent income, interest and other expenses, and sale value of the house after 20 years), plug them into excel or a financial calculator, and calculate the "IRR". If the IRR is less than the 10% you can earn on other investments of similar risk, then it's not as good of an investment.

Answer (score -1):

Never have business partners.  IMO dump it and take your money.

Comment: In the case of the question I take a lawn to buy the rest of the house and repair it.

Comment: Ignores the other option (to buy out the partner).  Besides, "**Never** have business partners" is absurdly silly.